# Meteor 0.8 upgrade affects jQueryMobile ListView refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile, meteor

I just upgraded to Meteor 0.8 and noticed that my listview refresh is no longer working meaning that I see data but the jQuery-Mobile style is not being applied. I'm using 1.4.2 and this worked fine with 0.7.2 of Meteor using:

```
   Template.requests.rendered = function(){
      if ($('[data-role="listview"]')) {
          $('[data-role="listview"]').listview().listview("refresh");
      }
   }
```

Has anyone else seen this behavior and knows of a fix?

This is what my template looks like:

```
<template name="requests">
    <div id="listview-content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="false" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
            {{#each items}}
            <li><a href="#listdetail" data-name="{{RequestedFor}}" data-transition="slide">{{RequestedFor}}<br><span
                    class="small">Requested new {{RequestedItem}} on {{formatDate dateSubmitted "short"}}</span></a>
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

The issue appears to be that the template rendered event is truly not yet rendered data, so it's trying to do a listview refresh on something that's not there yet.  For now, I do this hack, but that's not something I want to keep of course:

```
Template.requests.rendered = function(){
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
        if ($('[data-role="listview"]')) {
            $('[data-role="listview"]').listview().listview("refresh");
        }
    }, 300); //Must be >= 300ms to render the listview properly
};
```

Comment: if you're adding a fresh `ul`, use `.listview()` only. if you're adding `li` to an existing `ul`, use `.listview("refresh")` only.

Comment: I've tried both, but this doesn't work because the listview is not yet visible. I need a way to do this after the listview is visible and then I expect it to work. Problem is I can't seem to find a way to do that with meteor.

Comment: No error. Just doesn't apply the style.

Comment: I also faced this issue. It seems DOM is not ready when rendered is called.:(

Comment: try referring this answer "The recommended pattern is to put the contents of your {{#each}} in a separate template and tap into the rendered event of that template." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790936/meteor-0-8-0-failed-to-operate-dom-in-rendered-callback?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution based on the comments to the question and ultimately this [link](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes#New%20Rendered%20behaviour%20with%20external%20scripts%20e.g.%20jQuery). Basically, you just need to separate the list item as a separate template in your HTML and then add a JS `Template.template_name.rendered` function that will refresh the list view. It does get called every time there's a new item but only takes about 3ms to refresh the item.