# Meteor 0.8.0 - Failed to operate DOM in rendered callback

Tags: meteor

Before 0.8.0, the following code works perfectly.

```
<template name="carousel">
    <!--Here I used the carousel of Bootstrap-->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        {{#each counter}}
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{this}}"></li>
        {{/each}}
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            {{#each carousels}}
                <div class="item"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{src}}" ></a></div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
</template>

Template.carousel.helpers({
    carousels: function() {
        return Carousels.find();
    },
    counter: function() {
        return _.range(0, Carousels.find().count());
    }
});

Template.carousel.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.defer(function() {
        $('#myCarousel .carousel-indicators li:first').addClass('active');
        $('#myCarousel .item:first').addClass('active');
    });
}
```

But after updating to 0.8.0, adding 'active' class doesn't work any more.
Using Meteor.setTimeout instead of Meteor.defer, I finally find that it works only when the delay is long enough (sometimes longer than 150ms).

```
Template.carousel.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myCarousel .carousel-indicators li:first').addClass('active');
        $('#myCarousel .item:first').addClass('active');
    }, 150);
}
```

Why does this happen, and is there any better solution?

[Updated]
Now I use a simple isFirst helper to realize it. I think this is a better solution.

```
{{#each carousels}}
    <div class="item {{isFirst _id}}"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{src}}" ></a></div>
{{/each}}

Template.carousel.isFirst = function(id) {
    return Carousels.find().fetch()[0]._id == id ? 'active' : '';
}
```

As for the counter, I just make "counter" begin from 1, and the HTML is as follows:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
    {{#each counter}}
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{{this}}"></li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

Comment: Sounds like a race condition. But where and with what, I don't know.

Comment: Please checkout my answer for a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789821/meteor-0-8-blaze-how-to-update-rendered-changes-for-jquery-plugins). You can follow that pattern as well.

Answer (score 2):

Template.carousel.rendered only runs once in [Blaze](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze) (Meteor's new rendering engine), but it used to run multiple times in Spark (previous versions). This old behaviour worked because it ran before and after your {{#each}} block was rendered.

The problem here is that Template.carousel.rendered runs before your {{#each}} block is rendered, so those items don't exist yet.

The [recommended pattern](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/47Orrrz7kjg/Msfv1wMhEc4J) is to put the **contents** of your {{#each}} in a separate template and tap into the rendered event of *that* template.

By the way, Meteor.defer is no longer required.

Comment: Thanks. It works, but the rendered callback will be called multi times. It may cause some new problems sometimes.

Comment: @Vanitas you can get around that quickly by adding "active" if there are no nodes that already have it or by setting a "is_first_run" variable outside of rendered() and only running if that variable is false, then set it to true when it runs...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just updated the question to show my new solution, and rendered callback isn't needed any more. Thanks again.

Comment: So is your problem solved? If so, there was no need to put the answer in the question. Simply mark one of the answers as accepted. :) cheers.

Comment: Yes. I put my solution here for two reasons: 1.I don't use your solution at last; 2.To help people with similar problems.